# Is it right to say 'a marriage proposal to me from my beloved'?

Tags: grammar

Is it right to say:

> I was very excited when I heard a marriage proposal to me from my beloved ?

Comment: Yes, very excited is what you ought to be!  And it's better to hear a proposal to oneself than to some third party.

Comment: It would be much more common to phrase it: "I was very excited when my beloved asked me to marry him". This sounds very odd to me. It's probably grammatically OK but it sounds strange.

Comment: @Catija - does it sound strange because of **to me** being a bit excessive (because we tend to imply that it would be a proposal to her)?

Comment: @CopperKettle That would certainly help... but it makes it a bit ambiguous... the writer could easily fake out the audience and turn the sentence around: *I was very excited when I heard a marriage proposal from my beloved... until I realized he was asking Jenny and not me.* It's just so idiomatic to say "he proposed to me" that making it backwards seems odd.

Comment: Someone should mention that "my beloved" sounds rather old-fashioned. More contempory speakers are more likely to say, "I was very excited when my boyfriend asked me to marry him" (or, "...when my boyfriend *proposed*"). This is actually a pretty interesting question. If you could just give a little more information about what you want to know: (Does it sound natural? Is it grammatically correct?) and also tell us where you think it might be wrong (Is it the "proposal to me" part? The "from my beloved part"?), then we could reopen this question.

Answer (score 2):

It is grammatically correct to say such a thing, but it is an awkward-sounding phrasing.

Some more "natural" alternatives would be:

- when I received a marriage proposal from my beloved
- when my beloved proposed to me
- when my beloved asked me to marry him
- when I was proposed to by my beloved